# Remmina repatedly opens new tab

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I am trying to connect to remote desktop using remmina but it keeps opening new tab repeatedly making me unable to use it and is not getting connected in different subnet in same network.

[image]

Comment: The "hall of mirrors" effect suggests that you are connecting the remmina client to the same display that it is running on

Comment: but when i did it with rdp it was not happening that way.